# How to make Htaccess file call external IP block lists?

Tags: htaccess, ip-address

Well, I don’t know if this is an easy thing to do, but I haven’t figured it out yet.   Instead of continually updating my Htaccess file with newly updated country IP block lists   (because my htaccess file is now as long as a trip to the moon),  I’d like to include some bit of code in the main htaccess to “call” different IP lists, so I can easily re-upload a newly updated country ip block list to a folder of blocked countries (i use http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/ for my lists)

FOR EXAMPLE:

random website folder 
random website folder 
random website folder 
.HTACCESS  
Countryblocklist folder  ------inside this folder , 
 
                                      --->deny_nigeria.txt 
                                      --->deny_china.txt 
                                      --->deny_russia.txt 
                                      ---->deny_any_other_country.txt

Can anyone help me out with what code I could use inside the Htaccess to be able to call these foldered ipblock txt files???

(and please no jibes at me blocking countries lol, i really need to for my business, as hundreds from these countries have been playing havoc with my site for years now, also I cant use geo-ip thing, as i use bluehost for hosting)

Cheers guys.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to include external file for the block list. You can use [include directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#include) in httpd.conf only ,e.g.,

```
 Order Deny,Allow
 include conf/Countryblocklist/*
 Allow from all
```

with Deny in each IP. It requires server restart on each update, so you should consider blocking with script.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean.